# Strapi returns meta-data but data is null

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I’ve just started learning about Strapi, when I request data (GET) on an endpoint (/api/orders) it returns “meta data” but data is although orders exists in database
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all your entries are not as draft and they are published, this may be a reason nothing is returned.

[Strapi Draft and publish](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/concepts/draft-and-publish.html)